# how to use qt in python

Tags: python, qt

I am working on a module for 3D slicer. A chunk of the template code is pasted below. It is using qt for GUI. I need to add my own GUI here, But I am not able to find how to add toolbar here. I am not able to find any documentation regarding this. Whenever I google I get PyQt4, is that different from this ? So, my question is please explain the diference between qt and PyQt4 and how can I add toolbar here ?

```
     def __init__(self, widgetClass=None):
    self.parent = qt.QFrame()
    self.parent.setLayout( qt.QVBoxLayout() )

    # TODO: should have way to pop up python interactor
    self.buttons = qt.QFrame()
    self.buttons.setLayout( qt.QHBoxLayout() )
    self.parent.layout().addWidget(self.buttons)
    self.addDataButton = qt.QPushButton("Add Data")
    self.buttons.layout().addWidget(self.addDataButton)
    self.addDataButton.connect("clicked()",slicer.app.ioManager().openAddDataDialog)
    self.loadSceneButton = qt.QPushButton("Load Scene")
    self.buttons.layout().addWidget(self.loadSceneButton)
    self.loadSceneButton.connect("clicked()",slicer.app.ioManager().openLoadSceneDialog)
```

import statement

```
import vtk, qt, ctk, slicer
```

Comment: can u paste import statement ? i think it's the same as PyQt

Comment: @JayParikh added.

Comment: I think that this software use a PyQt wrapper which allow to use PySide2, PyQt5, PySide and PyQt4 with the same base code, see https://github.com/mottosso/Qt.py

Answer (score 0):

I think the form/GUI is created by tool. You can have a look at [this](http://www.cs.usfca.edu/~afedosov/qttut/)

You can add your PyQt4 code in this, that should work fine.

Comment: At least it doesn't seem to be generated by pyuic

Comment: can you please add a toolbar and menubar in above GUI to help me get started ?

Answer (score -1):

If the import statement is qt, 2 solution : it use an alias (it would be weird) or it use a pyqt wrapper which allow to use PySide2, PyQt5, PySide and PyQt4 the same base code.

Maybe this one : https://github.com/mottosso/Qt.py 
maybe another ... If you have a requirement.txt you should be able to know

Comment: can you please add a toolbar and menubar in above GUI to help me get started ?

Comment: Does this class inherit from QMainWindow ?

Answer (score -1):

> please explain the diference between qt and PyQt4

Qt is cross-platform application framework, using C++ extensions.
In order to use it in python you need a wrapper and this is what PyQt, PySide and the rest are. 
Check your application documentation and probably you will find if it uses PyQt4,5, PySide or something else.

Comment: can you please add a toolbar and menubar in above GUI to help me get started ?